# Left column not appearing on custom page/controller

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've created a custom page `devis` and its controller in Prestashop 1.6, but I'm unable to display any columns.

Controller :

```
class DevisController extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'devis';
    public $display_column_left = true;
    ...
}
```

In Theme configuration, my 'Devis' page appears and the left column is checked :

[image]

The "display or not" logic happens in `FrontController.php`'s constructor :

```
if (isset($this->php_self) && is_object(Context::getContext()->theme)) {
        $columns = Context::getContext()->theme->hasColumns($this->php_self);

        // Don't use theme tables if not configured in DB
        if ($columns) {
            $this->display_column_left  = $columns['left_column'];  // FALSE : why ?
            $this->display_column_right = $columns['right_column'];
        }
    }
```

I can force the column to display by doing `$this->display_column_left = true` but it's obviously not the way to do it.

Does someone know why `$columns['left_column']` is `false` ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not shop-level related? 'Cause to my knowledge left column is displayed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Sh*t...

As mentionned by @julien-lachal, the issue was shop-level related.

That means I was browsing the dashboard as "All the shops".

By choosing the desired shop, the left column in theme settings was actually disabled.

Big problems simple fixes...